# in flutter calendar, i need monthly calendar to be start from previous month 25th to current month 24th. example: mar month calendar: 25th feb - 24mar

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile, frontend

[example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvSoN.png)

I need calendar in flutter like above image. the monthly calendar starts from previous month 25th to current month 24th. for example: April month calendar: Mar25-Apr24th. develop this calendar using syncfusion flutter calendar or tablecalendar

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.